# separate print( ) results in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Python in Jupyternotebook. I mainly work with `hdf5` or `netcdf4` data, so there are always descriptions along with the data. When I want to read and view multiple data at the same time, I would use

```
print(A)
print(B)
print(C) 
...
```

Then the problem is that when the descriptions are really long, it is hard to distinguish which paragraphs are for which data. I tried this to help me separate them.

```
print(A)
print('-------------------------------')
print(B)
```

But this may introduce too many additional lines. Is there any smarter way to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `f-strings` like:

```
>>> A = "My A"
>>> print(f'This is A: \n{A}')
This is A: 
My A
```

OR

```
>>> print(f'### A ###\n{A}')
### A ###
My A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sep` argument, and can use `*` to produce pattern string:

```
print(A, '-'*20, B, sep = '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the inspiration from `@Vicrobot` and `@DuDoff`, I may use this:

```
print(A,B,C,D,E,sep = '\n##########################\n')
```